# How can I match only integers in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

So I have an array that goes like this:

```
my @nums = (1,2,12,24,48,120,360);
```

I want to check if there is an element that is ***not*** an integer inside that array without using loop. It goes like this:

```
if(grep(!/[^0-9]|\^$/,@nums)){
    die "Numbers are not in correct format.";
}else{
    #Do something
}
```

Basically, the format should not be like this (***Empty string is acceptable***):

```
1A
A2
@A
@
```

#######

More examples:

```
1,2,3,A3 = Unacceptable
1,2,###,2 = unacceptable
1,2,3A,4 = Unacceptable
1, ,3,4=Acceptable
1,2,3,360 = acceptable
```

I know that there is another way by using look like a number. But I can't use that for some reason (outside of my control/setup reasons). That's why I used the regex method.

My question is, even though the numbers are in not correct format (A60 for example), the condition always return False. Basically, it ignores the incorrect format.

Comment: `if (grep { /[^0-9]|^$/ } @nums) { say 'not all integers' }` ... like that?

Comment: Yes... that's what I put. Or am I missing the difference?

Comment: "_Yes... that's what I put._"  -- 1) No: your regex is negated, `!/.../`, which is then the opposite 2) More to the point, if this works for you -- as it seems? -- then what is the question?

Comment: The exclamation mark negates a true/false result.  So if the regex matches, that'd be "true", but with that exclamation in front of it `grep` gets a "false"; if regex fails then `grep` gets "true".

Comment: Can also use a library instead, which is clearer and  more efficient: `any` from `List::Util` -- `if (any { /[^0-9]|^$/ } @nums) { say 'not all integers' }`.  For this to run you need before to say `use List::Util qw(any);` (to load the `List::Util` library and import the symbol -- function name -- `any`).  This reads really clearly: if "`any`" one element from `@nums` matches a non-digit (`[^0-9]`) or (`|`) an empty string (`^$` -- nothing between beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of string), then `if` is true and its block runs

Comment: I've updated my post and put the question apologies. Unfortunately, I can't use that library as i'm not allowed to install the modules. :(

Comment: "_My question is, ..._"   -- ah, ok.  So I answered that in the comments above -- remove the `!` in front of the regex.  It reverses the logic and the result.  See my comments above.  (As for the library, it comes with Perl, it's in "core". So you can use it if you wish.)

Comment: One more thing: in the regex you do NOT want to escape the `^` :  when you use `\^` then that tries to match the literal `^` character.  But you don't want that, you want to use `^` for its special meaning in the regex: beginning of the string.  So, `/[^0-9]|^$/`.  See comments for some explanation, and the first comment for the complete expression.

Comment: Hi! The reason why I negate the grep is because I want something like this:

If this grep is NOT matching with this ReGex/Format then it will fail the script. Otherwise, then it will proceed.  For example: If the format of 1,2,3A,4 is not matching with this regex, then fail the script.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Also, for the escape character, thank you. I will remove it. :)

Comment: "_Am I missing something obvious here?_"  -- yes, exactly :) .. I get your logic, that's good -- but it got reversed.  So, you want to test each "number" for whether it contains anything other than digits, and if any one does the `if` should be "true".  So in grep you test for whether there is a non-digit, `/[^0-9]/` (this regex means any one character which is not a digit).  That's it.  That's all you want inside the `grep` block -- NO exclamation mark!  That would _negate_ the logic.

Comment: Also, I tried ^[0-9] and it is working but it only checks the first string (A3, @4, A) but it will ignore 3A,4B which is not acceptable hence, I feel like [^0-9] is not working.

Comment: Let's take an example.  Imagine an array `(71, '23a')`.  The `grep` checks each number in turn: 1) for `71`, regex `/[^0-9]/` fails (no non-digits in `71`) 2) for `22a` that `[^0-9]` fails for 2, fails for 3 -- and matches `a`!  So `grep` returns true for that one and `if` is true.  That's correct, that array _did_ have a non-integer element.  Now if you put `!` in front of the regex that is reversed...

Comment: Regex:  `[]` is a "character class" -- `[abc]` matches a character which is either `a` or `b` or `c`.  But, when it starts with `^`, then it matches a character which _isn't_ one of those inside -- so `[^abc]` matches a character which _isn't_ any one of `a,b,c`.  So `[^0-9]` matches a character which isn't any one of the digits 0-9.  On the other hand, in `/^[0-9]/` that `^` means the beginning of the string (since it's not inside the `[]`), and `[0-9]` means a digit.  So this regex means a digit at the beginning of the string.  The opposite,kinda

Comment: That `^[0-9]` is working (for the first character only), because it is the opposite logic -- and then you negate it with `!` ... so turned around twice :).  But it's simpler to just check for a non-digit, `/[^0-9]/`, and if `grep` catches any one like that (any element matches, so has a non-digit), then that's it, the `if` is true...

Comment: I'll leave you with this now, hopefully it helps. I'll be back in the morning but perhaps somebody comes along and writes it up as an answer (I didn't expect it to turn into so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You say in the comments that you don't want to use modules because you can't install them, but there are many core modules that should come with Perl (although some systems screw this up).

zdim's answer in the comments is to look for anything that is not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9. That's the negated character class `[^0-9]`. A `grep` in scalar context returns the number of items that match:

```
my $found_non_ints = grep { /[^0-9]/ } @items;
```

Instead of that, I'd go back to the non-negated character class and match string that only has zero or more digits. To do this, anchor the pattern to the absolute start and end of the string:

```
my $found_non_ints = grep { ! /\A[0-9]*\z/  } @items;
```

But, this doesn't really match integers. It matches positive whole numbers (and zero). If you want to match negative numbers as well, allow an optional `-` at the start of the string:

```
my $found_non_ints = grep { ! /\A-?[0-9]*\z/  } @items;
```

That `-` would be a problem in the negated character class.

Also, you don't want the `$` anchor here: that allows a possible newline to match at the end, and that's a non-digit (the `\Z` is the same for the end of the string). Also, the meaning of `$` can change based on the setting of the `/m` flag, which might be set with default regex flags.

Here's a short program with your sample data. Note that you need to decide how to split up the list; does whitespace matter? I decided to remove whitespace around the comma:

```
#!perl
use v5.10;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my $found_non_ints = grep { ! /\A[0-9]*\z/  } split /\s*,\s*/;
    say "$_ => Found $found_non_ints non-ints";
    }

__DATA__
1A
A2
@A
@
1,2,3,A3
1,2,###,2
1,2,3A,4
1, ,3,4
1,,3,4
1,2,3,360
```

Comment: "This excludes the empty string". The question (currently) says that is what is wanted.

Comment: The question currently says that the empty string is acceptable. Yes, everything is a mess and I had to read this several times, but the empty string is allowed.

Comment: Too many negations :-/ What I meant is that the wording of your answer seems to imply you think it is a bug that `$found_non_ints = grep {/[^0-9]/} ("")` == 0 but that that seems to be what is wanted looking at the sample input provided.

Comment: I can't find a situation where `/[^0-9]/` is not equivalent to `!/\A[0-9]*\z/`. Am I missing something subtle?

Comment: @jhnc "_can't find a situation_" ... the `/[^0-9]/` "allows" for an empty string (it doesn't match it!), and that's not a number so it should match it so that we can disallow it.  That's why in my first comment there's in fact `/[^0-9]|^$/`, which catches the empty string as well.  Not pretty but it works.  (The rest of our discussion is about everything else though so this got lost in it...)  This solution is conceptually simpler -- is it not a number? But then there are negations... there has to be something

Comment: @jhnc yeah, I think I was mixing that up with something else I was thinking about–probably the minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed in the question gets close, except that the logic got reversed and there is an error in a regex pattern.  One way for it:

```
if ( grep { /[^0-9] | ^$/x } @nums ) { say 'not all integers' }
```

Regex explanation

- `[]` is a character class: it matches any one of the characters listed inside (so `[abc]` matches either of `a`, `b`, or `c`) -- *but* when it starts with a `^` it matches any character *not* listed; so `[^abc]` matches any char not being either of `a`, `b`, or `c`. The pattern `0-9` inside a character class specifies all digits in that range (and we can also use `a-z` and `A-Z`)

  So `[^0-9]` matches any character that is not a digit
- Then that is `or`-ed by `|` with a `^$`: `^` matches beginning of the string and `$` is for the end of it. So `^$` match a string without anything -- an empty string!  We need to account for that as `[^0-9]` doesn't while an array element *can* be an empty string.  (It can also be a `undef` but from my understanding that is not possible with actual data, and a regex on `undef` would draw a warning.)

  Note that `$` allows for a newline as well, and that `^` and `$` may change their meaning if `/m` modifier is in use, matching on linefeeds *inside* a string.  However, in all these cases we'd be matching a non-digit, which is precisely the point here
- `/x` modifier makes it disregard literal spaces inside so we can space things out for easier reading.  (It also allows for newlines and comments with `#`, so complex patterns can be organized and documented very nicely)

So that's all -- the regex tries to match anything that shouldn't be in an integer (assumed to be strictly positive in OP's data).

If it matches any such, in any one of the array elements, then `grep` returns a list which isn't empty (but has at least one element) and that is "true" under `if`. So we caught a non-integer and we go into `if`'s block to deal with that.

A little aside: we can also declare and populate an array right inside the `if` condition, to catch all those non-integers:

```
if ( my @non_ints = grep { /[^0-9] | ^$/x } @nums ) { 
    say 'Non-integers: ', join ' ', map { "|$_|" } @non_ints;
}
```

This also reads more nicely, telling by the array name what we're after in that complicated condition: "non_ints." I put `||` around each item in print to be able to see an empty string.<sup>†</sup>

Now, when you put an exclamation mark in front of that regex, it *reverses* the true/false return from the regex and our code goes haywire.  So drop that `!`.

The other error is in escaping the `^` by having `\^`.  This would match a literal `^` character, robbing `^` of its special meaning as a pattern in regex, explained above.  So drop that `\`.

---

One other way is in using an extremely useful [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util) library, which is "core" (so it is normally installed with Perl, even though that *can* get messed up).

Among a number of essential functions it gives us `any`, and with it we have

```
use List::Util qw(any);

if ( any { /[^0-9]|^$/ } @nums ) { say 'not all integers' }
```

I like `any` firstly because the name of the function includes at least a part of the needed logic, making code that much clearer and easier to comprehend: is there `any` element of `@nums` for which the code in the block is true?  So `any` element which contains a non-digit?  Precisely what is needed here.

Then, another advantage is that `any` will quit as soon as it finds one match, while `grep` continues through the whole list. But this efficiency advantage shows only on very large arrays or a *lot* of repeated checks. Also, on the other hand sometimes we want to count *all* instances.

I'd also like to point out some of `any`'s siblings: `none` and `notall`.  These names themselves also capture a good deal of logic, making otherwise possibly convoluted code that much clearer.  Browse through this library to get accustomed to what is in there.

---

<sup>†</sup> A program with your test data

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @nums = split /\s*,\s*/;
    say "Data: @nums";
    
    if ( my @non_ints = grep { /[^0-9] | ^$/x } @nums ) { 
        say 'Non-ints: ', join ' ', map { "|$_|" } @non_ints;
    }
    say '---';
}
    
__DATA__
1A
A2
@A
@
1,2,3,A3
1,2,###,2
1,2,3A,4
1, ,3,4
1,2,3,360
```

Comment: This summarizes much of the long comment thread